# Importing Arraylist to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have an ArrayString with some data that i want to be printed on a GUI, i started using JPanel and the such and ended up with windowbuilder on Eclipse to help me modify the visual aspects, i think that my code is horrible (or at least looks like it) I have found some similar threads to my question but i don't really grasp the idea:

Could i not use a Jtable instead of what looks like a load of crap? I just can't get my head round the JTable, i want it to look just like my code output but i don't understand how the table would read the arraystring and the "output it" like my table, i don't know how to implement the combo boxes either... any help would be of much use, thanks!

Edit: my first idea was that each "Jtextfield" would "import" each data line but im thinking that this is very unefficient and probably prone to coding errors when i could make my life simpler?

here's an image of the rendered code: http://i57.tinypic.com/34j7mtd.jpg

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class InfoVehiculos extends JFrame {
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    private JTextField textField_5;
    private JTextField textField_6;
    private JTextField textField_7;
    private JTextField textField_8;
    private JTextField textField_9;
    private JTextField textField_10;
    private JTextField textField_11;
    private JTextField textField_12;
    private JTextField textField_13;
    private JTextField textField_14;
    private JTextField textField_15;
    private JTextField textField_16;
    private JTextField textField_17;
    private JTextField textField_18;
    private JTextField textField_19;
    private JTextField textField_20;
    private JTextField textField_21;
    private JTextField textField_22;
    private JTextField textField_23;
    private JTextField textField_24;
    private JTextField textField_25;
    private JTextField textField_26;
    private JTextField textField_27;
    private JTextField textField_28;
    private JTextField textField_29;
    private JTextField textField_30;
    private JTextField textField_31;
    private JTextField textField_32;
    private JTextField textField_33;
    private JTextField textField_34;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InfoVehiculos frame = new InfoVehiculos();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public InfoVehiculos() 
    {
        setTitle("Informacion");
        setBounds(100, 100, 495, 309);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblTipo = new JLabel("Tipo");
        lblTipo.setBounds(39, 24, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblTipo);

        JLabel lblMarca = new JLabel("Marca");
        lblMarca.setBounds(95, 24, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblMarca);

        JLabel lblModelo = new JLabel("Modelo");
        lblModelo.setBounds(151, 24, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblModelo);

        JLabel lblMatrcula = new JLabel("Matricula");
        lblMatrcula.setBounds(207, 24, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblMatrcula);

        JLabel lblItv = new JLabel("ITV");
        lblItv.setBounds(281, 24, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblItv);

        JLabel lblParking = new JLabel("Parking");
        lblParking.setBounds(337, 24, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblParking);

        JLabel lblEstado = new JLabel("Estado");
        lblEstado.setBounds(410, 24, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblEstado);

        //Cada combo box se puede desplegar para A/B/C
        JComboBox ComboTipo = new JComboBox();
        ComboTipo.setBounds(25, 49, 35, 20);
        ComboTipo.addItem("A");
        ComboTipo.addItem("B");
        ComboTipo.addItem("C");
        getContentPane().add(ComboTipo);

        JComboBox ComboTipo1 = new JComboBox();
        ComboTipo1.setBounds(25, 80, 35, 20);
        ComboTipo1.addItem("A");
        ComboTipo1.addItem("B");
        ComboTipo1.addItem("C");
        getContentPane().add(ComboTipo1);

        JComboBox ComboTipo2 = new JComboBox();
        ComboTipo2.setBounds(25, 111, 35, 20);
        ComboTipo2.addItem("A");
        ComboTipo2.addItem("B");
        ComboTipo2.addItem("C");
        getContentPane().add(ComboTipo2);

        JComboBox ComboTipo3 = new JComboBox();
        ComboTipo3.setBounds(25, 142, 35, 20);
        ComboTipo3.addItem("A");
        ComboTipo3.addItem("B");
        ComboTipo3.addItem("C");
        getContentPane().add(ComboTipo3);

        JComboBox ComboTipo4 = new JComboBox();
        ComboTipo4.setBounds(25, 173, 35, 20);
        ComboTipo4.addItem("A");
        ComboTipo4.addItem("B");
        ComboTipo4.addItem("C");
        getContentPane().add(ComboTipo4);

        JComboBox ComboTipo5 = new JComboBox();
        ComboTipo5.setBounds(25, 204, 35, 20);
        ComboTipo5.addItem("A");
        ComboTipo5.addItem("B");
        ComboTipo5.addItem("C");
        getContentPane().add(ComboTipo5);

        JComboBox ComboTipo6 = new JComboBox();
        ComboTipo6.setBounds(25, 235, 35, 20);
        ComboTipo6.addItem("A");
        ComboTipo6.addItem("B");
        ComboTipo6.addItem("C");
        getContentPane().add(ComboTipo6);

        //Cada combobox tiene activo o inactivo
        JComboBox ComboEstado = new JComboBox();
        ComboEstado.setBounds(408, 49, 50, 20);
        ComboEstado.addItem("Activo");
        ComboEstado.addItem("Inactivo");
        getContentPane().add(ComboEstado);

        JComboBox ComboEstado1 = new JComboBox();
        ComboEstado1.setBounds(408, 80, 50, 20);
        ComboEstado1.addItem("Activo");
        ComboEstado1.addItem("Inactivo");
        getContentPane().add(ComboEstado1);

        JComboBox ComboEstado2 = new JComboBox();
        ComboEstado2.setBounds(408, 111, 50, 20);
        ComboEstado2.addItem("Activo");
        ComboEstado2.addItem("Inactivo");
        getContentPane().add(ComboEstado2);

        JComboBox ComboEstado3 = new JComboBox();
        ComboEstado3.setBounds(408, 142, 50, 20);
        ComboEstado3.addItem("Activo");
        ComboEstado3.addItem("Inactivo");
        getContentPane().add(ComboEstado3);

        JComboBox ComboEstado4 = new JComboBox();
        ComboEstado4.setBounds(408, 173, 50, 20);
        ComboEstado4.addItem("Activo");
        ComboEstado4.addItem("Inactivo");
        getContentPane().add(ComboEstado4);

        JComboBox ComboEstado5 = new JComboBox();
        ComboEstado5.setBounds(408, 204, 50, 20);
        ComboEstado5.addItem("Activo");
        ComboEstado5.addItem("Inactivo");
        getContentPane().add(ComboEstado5);

        JComboBox ComboEstado6 = new JComboBox();
        ComboEstado6.setBounds(408, 235, 50, 20);
        ComboEstado6.addItem("Activo");
        ComboEstado6.addItem("Inactivo");
        getContentPane().add(ComboEstado6);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(70, 49, 71, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(70, 80, 71, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setBounds(70, 111, 71, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);

        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setBounds(70, 142, 71, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_3);
        textField_3.setColumns(10);

        textField_4 = new JTextField();
        textField_4.setBounds(70, 173, 71, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_4);
        textField_4.setColumns(10);

        textField_5 = new JTextField();
        textField_5.setBounds(70, 204, 72, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_5);
        textField_5.setColumns(10);

        textField_6 = new JTextField();
        textField_6.setBounds(70, 235, 72, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_6);
        textField_6.setColumns(10);

        textField_7 = new JTextField();
        textField_7.setBounds(151, 49, 48, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_7);
        textField_7.setColumns(10);

        textField_8 = new JTextField();
        textField_8.setBounds(151, 80, 48, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_8);
        textField_8.setColumns(10);

        textField_9 = new JTextField();
        textField_9.setBounds(151, 111, 48, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_9);
        textField_9.setColumns(10);

        textField_10 = new JTextField();
        textField_10.setBounds(151, 142, 48, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_10);
        textField_10.setColumns(10);

        textField_11 = new JTextField();
        textField_11.setBounds(151, 173, 48, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_11);
        textField_11.setColumns(10);

        textField_12 = new JTextField();
        textField_12.setBounds(151, 204, 48, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_12);
        textField_12.setColumns(10);

        textField_13 = new JTextField();
        textField_13.setBounds(151, 235, 48, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_13);
        textField_13.setColumns(10);

        textField_14 = new JTextField();
        textField_14.setBounds(207, 49, 59, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_14);
        textField_14.setColumns(10);

        textField_15 = new JTextField();
        textField_15.setBounds(207, 80, 59, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_15);
        textField_15.setColumns(10);

        textField_16 = new JTextField();
        textField_16.setBounds(207, 111, 59, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_16);
        textField_16.setColumns(10);

        textField_17 = new JTextField();
        textField_17.setBounds(207, 142, 59, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_17);
        textField_17.setColumns(10);

        textField_18 = new JTextField();
        textField_18.setBounds(207, 173, 59, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_18);
        textField_18.setColumns(10);

        textField_19 = new JTextField();
        textField_19.setBounds(207, 204, 59, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_19);
        textField_19.setColumns(10);

        textField_20 = new JTextField();
        textField_20.setBounds(207, 235, 59, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_20);
        textField_20.setColumns(10);

        textField_21 = new JTextField();
        textField_21.setBounds(269, 49, 32, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_21);
        textField_21.setColumns(10);

        textField_22 = new JTextField();
        textField_22.setBounds(269, 80, 32, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_22);
        textField_22.setColumns(10);

        textField_23 = new JTextField();
        textField_23.setBounds(269, 111, 32, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_23);
        textField_23.setColumns(10);

        textField_24 = new JTextField();
        textField_24.setBounds(269, 142, 32, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_24);
        textField_24.setColumns(10);

        textField_25 = new JTextField();
        textField_25.setBounds(269, 173, 32, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_25);
        textField_25.setColumns(10);

        textField_26 = new JTextField();
        textField_26.setBounds(269, 204, 32, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_26);
        textField_26.setColumns(10);

        textField_27 = new JTextField();
        textField_27.setBounds(269, 235, 32, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_27);
        textField_27.setColumns(10);

        textField_28 = new JTextField();
        textField_28.setBounds(312, 49, 86, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_28);
        textField_28.setColumns(10);

        textField_29 = new JTextField();
        textField_29.setBounds(312, 80, 86, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_29);
        textField_29.setColumns(10);

        textField_30 = new JTextField();
        textField_30.setBounds(312, 111, 86, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_30);
        textField_30.setColumns(10);

        textField_31 = new JTextField();
        textField_31.setBounds(312, 142, 86, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_31);
        textField_31.setColumns(10);

        textField_32 = new JTextField();
        textField_32.setBounds(312, 173, 86, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_32);
        textField_32.setColumns(10);

        textField_33 = new JTextField();
        textField_33.setBounds(312, 204, 86, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_33);
        textField_33.setColumns(10);

        textField_34 = new JTextField();
        textField_34.setBounds(312, 235, 86, 20);
        getContentPane().add(textField_34);
        textField_34.setColumns(10);

    }
}
```

Comment: use .toArray() method to port the ArrayList to Array, then use it in the constructor or JTable

Comment: Read about DefaultTableModel and JTable. It will be very easy if you just want to display data.

Comment: `Could i not use a Jtable instead` - that is what I would suggest. It would get rid of all the variables and your null layout code. `i want it to look just like my code output but i don't understand how the table would read the arraystring` Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for working examples. You would need to load the data from the Array into the TableModel, using the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel`. It also shows how to use combo boxes.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I used to null to make sure each Jtext etc was in the position i wanted but i now see how gridlayout will do this automatically for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create table and model, then create column headers:

```
DefaultTableModel dftModel = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable mytable = new JTable(dftModel);
myTable.setColumnIdentifiers(new String [] {"Tipo","Column 1","Column 2","Column 3"});
```

Add your rows from you arraylist however you want:

```
myTable.addRow(new String[] {"",yourArrayList.get(1),"blah","blah"});
```

Add your Tipo Combo Box like this:

```
String [] tipArray = {"A","B","C"};
DefaultComboBoxModel comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(tipArray);
JComboBox ComboTipo = new JComboBox(comboModel);
mytable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(ComboTipo));
```

Comment: And how would i change the cells in the table to combo boxes? just far left and right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526917/load-arraylist-data-into-jtable i was thinking of something like the last example

Comment: Take a look at this example and let me know if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355712/adding-jcombobox-to-a-jtable-cell

Comment: @pablo, You probably already figured it out, but I edited the code above to show you how I would add the combo boxes to the table.

Answer (score 0):

- **Don't** use `null` Layout at all. Avoid `setBounds()` if possible.
- There is no need of calling `setBounds()` if you uses a proper layout.
- Respect the Layout Manager and handover the responsibility of the component positioning and sizing to the Layout Manager that's why it's made for it.

---

The same layout you can achieved by using [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) or [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html).

For more info have a look at below links:

- [How to Use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)
- [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: Thanks! I did think it would help but i chose null to make sure everything was where i wanted but as you said if this does it automatically....

Comment: @pablo If you uses any Layout then it's the responsibility of the Layout Manager itself to manage the position and size of the components but in case of `null` Layout.

Comment: GridLayout is good for discrete components (e.g. numbered buttons in a phone keyboard arrangement) but the question is about a row-by-row GUI for an arbitrary sequence of similar entities, the most typical use case for JTable and TableModel. 


A GridLayout containing appropriate controls for each column would be laid out correctly, but it would be a primitive and cumbersome reimplementation of JTable functionality (managing arbitrary row counts, maintaining a model, dynamically creating and swapping widgets, etc.).