# Putting an array of objects into a table - Java

Tags: java, user-interface, jtable

I have a student object with the following attributes:

```
private String forename;
private String surname;
private String id;
private char gender;
private String street;
private String locality;
private String postcode;
private String email;
```

I have several of these objects stored in an ArrayList and wanted to know the best way to get them into a JTable with columns named after the attributes above.

Comment: Have you tried something? If yes, why do you think it's not ideal?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526917/load-arraylist-data-into-jtable

Answer (score 3):

You can use do it simply like this. or check this answer as well.[Load arrayList data into JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526917/load-arraylist-data-into-jtable)

```
  public void populateReadersTable(ReaderList readerList) {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTableReaders.getModel();
        model.setRowCount(0);
        model.setColumnCount(0);
        model.addColumn("ID");
        model.addColumn("First Name");
        model.addColumn("Last Name");
        model.addColumn("Email");
        model.addColumn("Mobile");
        model.addColumn("Street");
        model.addColumn("City");
        model.addColumn("Postal Code");
        model.addColumn("National ID");

        for (Reader reader : readerList) {
            model.addRow(reader.toStringArray());
        }

    }
```