# How to populate Jtable with values from Arraylist (Null Pointer Exception in Jtables)

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, jtable, tablemodel

I am attempting to create a gui with two Jtables. One which outputs object Bike (if avaliable) and one which outputs object Rent. However Default Table Model keeps returning Null Point Exception. How do I populate a JTable with an arraylist of values then add it to a JPanel Grid Layout.

I have attempted to use Default Table Model and TableModel as well as search for the solution to not avail. This is for a basic GUI school project

Main Class where arrays are stored

```
public static final ArrayList<Bike> bikes = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final ArrayList<Rent> rents = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Rent> toRemove = new ArrayList<Rent>();


    //Create variables
    private int customerID = 0;
    private final LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();

    //Main Method
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //Create gui
        GUI fr = new GUI();
        fr.setSize(1000, 600);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        //Create Initial Objects and fill Arrays
        bikes.add(new Bike("Tarmac Disk Expert", 6000.00, "Mountain", true));
        bikes.add(new Bike("Epic Hardtail Comp", 3500.00, "Mountain", true));
        bikes.add(new Bike("Chisel Comp", 2000.00, "Road", true));
        bikes.add(new Bike("Roubaix Sport", 3500.00, "Road", false));
        bikes.add(new Bike("Turbo Levi Comp", 9500.00, "City", false));
        bikes.add(new Bike("Venge Pro", 9400.00, "City", true));
        bikes.add(new EBike("Turbo Como 2.0 650B", 4500.00, "Ebike", true, "Full Power"));
        bikes.add(new EBike("Turbo Kenevo Expert", 9500.00, "Ebike", true, "Full Power"));
        bikes.add(new EBike("Turbo Levo FSR", 5600.00, "Ebike", true, "Full Power"));
        bikes.add(new EBike("Turbo Vado 4.0", 5600.00, "Ebike", true, "Power Assisted"));
        bikes.add(new EBike("S-Works Turbo Levo", 4000.00, "Ebike", true, "Power Assisted"));
        bikes.add(new EBike("Turbo Como 2.0 Low Entry", 6600.00, "Ebike", true, "Power Assisted"));
        customers.add(new Customer(0001, "John Smith", true, "Roubaix Sport"));
        customers.add(new Customer(0002, "Madamn Tuscoue", false, "N/A"));
        customers.add(new Customer(0003, "James Lafroix", true, "Turbo Levi Comp"));
        rents.add(new Rent(0001, "John Smith", true, "Roubaix Sport", LocalDate.of(2019, 03, 06), LocalDate.of(2019, 04, 05), 30, true));
        rents.add(new Rent(0003, "James Lafroix", true, "Turbo Levi Comp", LocalDate.of(2019, 03, 20), LocalDate.of(2019, 04, 19), 30, false));
```

Bike Constructor

```
public Bike(String name, double price, String type, boolean available) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.type = type;
        this.available = available;
    }
```

Rent Constructor

```
public Rent(int customerID, String customerName, boolean renting, String bikeRented, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, int duration, boolean overdue) {
        super(customerID, customerName, renting, bikeRented);
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.overdue = overdue;
    }
```

Lastly GUI class in which I am attempting to to use Default Table Model

```
 public class GUI extends JFrame {
    BikeNow controller = new BikeNow();

    JPanel headingPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel saveDetailsPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel customerPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel bikePanel = new JPanel();
    JTable bikesAvaliable, currentRents;
    JButton btnaddCustomer, btnviewCustomer, btnaddRent, btnreturnRent, btnsaveFile, btnloadFile;
    JLabel lblHeading = new JLabel("Welcome to Bike Now");


    public GUI() {
        super("Bike Now");

        Font headingFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 60);

        this.headingPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        this.headingPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        lblHeading.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        lblHeading.setFont(headingFont);
        this.headingPanel.add(this.lblHeading);
        this.add(this.headingPanel, "North");

        String[] columnNames1 = {"Bike Name", "Cost Per Day", "Bike Type"};
        String[] columnNames2 = {"Start Date", "End Date", "Duration", "OverDue", "Customer ID", "Customer Name", "Renting", "Bike Rented"};


        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)bikesAvaliable.getModel();

        Object rowData[] = new Object[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < controller.bikes.size(); i++) {
            rowData[0] = controller.bikes.get(i).getName();
            rowData[1] = controller.bikes.get(i).getPrice();
            rowData[2] = controller.bikes.get(i).getType();
            model.addRow(rowData);
        }

        bikesAvaliable.setModel(model);
        //currentRents.setModel(tableModel2);

        this.centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        this.centerPanel.add(this.bikesAvaliable);
        this.centerPanel.add(bikesAvaliable.getTableHeader());
        //this.centerPanel.add(currentRents.getTableHeader());
        //this.centerPanel.add(this.currentRents);
        this.add(this.centerPanel, "Center");
    }

}
```

NullPointError appearing at line

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)bikesAvaliable.getModel();
```

in Gui class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `bikesAvailable` variable isn't properly initialized. Just instantiate it with `JTable bikesAvailable = new JTable();`

or use another constructor: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html

Comment: Thank you! That removed the Null Point Exception. Now to figure out how to add arraylist data to table

Comment: @Chornologic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526917/load-arraylist-data-into-jtable

Answer (score 1):

It appears that bikesAvaliable has no object assigned to it in the GUI class. A way to fix this, would be to create your bikesAvalible object in the gui class, or pass the bikesAvaible object you created in the other class to the the gui class so it can be used.